# What is the error in the following code for matrix mutliplication?

Tags: python

I have been trying to perform matrix multiplication with the traditional method which we use in C or C++ , but it continuously giving error at line number 27.

How I can fix?

[image]

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: I have just uploaded image of code with it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see it.

Comment: *"I have just uploaded image of code with it"* - why? It's test, post a [mcve] **as text**.

Comment: please do click at 1 before the question

Comment: Please add the code and what error found. So we are easily found.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since by using an image in your description you didn't give us a way to copy-paste your code so I rewrote it from scratch:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

matrixes_names = ('first', 'second')

def asks_matrix_size(which_one):
    string_answer = input("Enter the number of rows and the number of colums (space separated) of the {} matrix: ".format(which_one))
    answer = tuple(int(x) for x in string_answer.split())

    return answer

matrixes_size = []
matrixes_size.append(asks_matrix_size(matrixes_names[0]))

matrixes = [[], []]

for row_being_filled in range(matrixes_size[0][0]):
    row_received = input("Enter the {} elements (space separated) of row number {} of the {} matrix: ".format(matrixes_size[0][1],
                                                                                                          row_being_filled + 1,
                                                                                                          matrixes_names[0]))
    row = [int(x) for x in row_received.split()]
    matrixes[0].append(row)

matrixes_size.append(asks_matrix_size(matrixes_names[1]))

if matrixes_size[1][0] == matrixes_size[0][1]:
    matrixes[1] = [[] for _ in range(matrixes_size[1][1])]

    for row_being_filled in range(matrixes_size[1][0]):
        row_received = input("Enter the {} elements (space separated) of row number {} of the {} matrix: ".format(matrixes_size[1][1],
                                                                                                              row_being_filled + 1,
                                                                                                              matrixes_names[1]))
        row = [int(x) for x in row_received.split()]
        for (column, row_transposed) in zip(row, matrixes[1]):
            row_transposed.append(column)

    solution_matrix = []

    for row_from_first in matrixes[0]:
        solution_row = []
        for column_from_second in matrixes[1]:
            solution_row.append(sum(x*y for (x, y) in zip(row_from_first, column_from_second)))
        solution_matrix.append(solution_row)

    print(solution_matrix)
else:
    print("Matrix multiplication is not possible")
```

We can further condense the solution if we are permitted to ask for the size of the two matrixes before asking for their content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

matrixes_names = ('first', 'second')

def asks_matrix_size(which_one):
    string_answer = input("Enter the number of rows and the number of colums (space separated) of the {} matrix: ".format(which_one))
    return tuple(int(x) for x in string_answer.split())

matrixes_size = [asks_matrix_size(x) for x in matrixes_names]

if matrixes_size[1][0] == matrixes_size[0][1]:

    def ask_matrix_elements(size, matrix_name):
        print("")
        for row_being_filled in range(size[0]):
            row_received = input("Enter the {} elements (space separated) of row number {} of the {} matrix: ".format(size[1],
                                                                                                              row_being_filled + 1,
                                                                                                              matrix_name))
            yield tuple(int(x) for x in row_received.split())

    matrixes = [tuple(ask_matrix_elements(x, y)) for (x, y) in zip(matrixes_size, matrixes_names)]

    # Transposing the second matrix (to simplify the computation of the solution)
    matrixes[1] = tuple(zip(*matrixes[1]))

    solution_matrix = tuple(tuple(sum(x*y for (x, y) in zip(row_from_first, column_from_second))
                                  for column_from_second in matrixes[1])
                            for row_from_first in matrixes[0])

    print(solution_matrix)
else:
    print("Matrix multiplication is not possible")
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't declared type of sum variable, and also propably You are going to assign array to double

Comment: Hello Michal, Your answer is wrong because sum variable in only store the multiplication of two number (ie. sum = 3 * 4) so why require assign array to sum variable.

Comment: Isn't 
'a = [[],[]]'
 declaration an array of arrays?